# ax.axvline in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a vertical line in matplotlib.  I have used Pandas in the past and used `ax.axvline(x=__)` to place my line.  I am trying to do this without Pandas' built in matplotlib calls, and having some trouble.

```
def stupid_plot(forecast_date, df, figsize):
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = figsize
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i in ['oil', 'wat_inj']:
        if i=='oil':
            style = '-'
        else:
            style = ':'

        for (j,k) in zip(pct_str_list, color_list):
            y = df[i + '_' + j]
            x = df['date']
            ax.plot(x,y, color=k, ls=style)

        for (i,j) in zip(['oil_0', 'water_0'], ['-', ':']):
            x_historical = df['date'][df['date']<=forecast_date]
            y_historical = df[i][df['date']<=forecast_date]
            ax.plot(x,y, color='black', ls=j)

ax.set_title('what the hell?')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.axvline(x=forecast_date) # error here <<<<<<------
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here. "Some trouble" is not a useful problem description. Also provide a [mcve], such that someone can copy and paste it and reproduce "some trouble".

Comment: If you read my post carefully, I explain that "I'm trying to plot a vertical line."  That's what is throwing an error.

You might also see the # error here <<<<<<----

If you know the syntax to plot a vertical line for ax, please let me know.  If not, your snarkiness is not appreciated.

Comment: There is no statement about the actual error message, also your code is not runnable to reproduce the error. How people are supposed to know what is in `df`?

Comment: Somebody familiar with matplotlib syntax should know how to produce a vertical line.  You shouldn't have to reproduce the code.  I have posted the answer below.

Comment: Was the down-vote really necessary?  I took the time to answer my own question, and it runs fine now.

Answer (score -1):

I found a link to ax.axhline, and just changed it to ax.axvline (https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html)

```
    ax.axvline(x=forecast_date, ls='--')
```